# integration of power BI report and dataset with other application

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I want power BI datasets updated by the application . It can be asp.net or console application .

So, can anyone help me out with this problem as I am not getting any solution to this problem.

Comment: when you say updating the dataset, do you want to update the structure of the dataset or you want to update data in dataset?

Answer (score 0):

You can create and push data to data sets programmatically:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt203551.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt203566.aspx

If you're looking to refresh a data set created through the UI in PowerBI.com or by publishing a Power BI Desktop file to PowerBI.com, there isn't one as yet.  You can submit an idea to ideas.powerbi.com to help track that.

But the best/easiest way to architect this solution is to use a Direct Query connection like with Azure SQL so that your data is always up to date once it is inserted into the underlying data store.
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-use-directquery/

You can find a sample for how to push data to a data set here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-CSharp/tree/master/samples/consoleapp/getting-started-for-dotnet-import

Comment: thanks, but can you please provide me an sample app or video link because I am not Getting that "What is Redirect URI " "what is resource URI"

Comment: I provided a link in my answer above.